# Access forbidden! Xampp localhost

Tags: php, xampp

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.28 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

i have tried adding this
to my config file
 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted

went into my Xampp folder xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.c­onf editted that to Allow from all...still nothing ..same error.... any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you have a valid file on localhost directory. I mean add an index.html file into root and try to enter http://localhost/index.html

Comment: I have a directory with some php files i can access but when I added a second for another project in the same directory I get that error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting my project folder into the htdocs directory I created a new folder with a new name and pasted the project files in it and it is working fine now. I can't seem to be able to access the files if they are in the copied folder

Answer (score 0):

This problem is common on Mac.

Start by creating a new folder in htdocs. Then Copy all your files to the new folder.

Instead of copying/moving the project folder to htdocs.
This should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).